# Application icon won't change to .ico image

Tags: c#, icons

I've made a C# program in Visual Studio and changed the icon in the Forms properties but it only changes in the top left corner of the application.

How can I get it to change the actual icon like if the application was on the desktop. Do I have to publish it? Will getting it straight from the debug folder not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to: Specify an Application Icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx)  on MSDN:

> - In Solution Explorer, choose a project node (not the Solution node).
>     On the menu bar, choose Project, Properties.
> - When the Project Designer appears, choose the Application tab.
> - Near the Icon list, choose the  button, and then browse to the location of the icon file that you want.

This will change the icon as it appears in, say, Windows Explorer or your desktop.

Comment: thanks, i just changed it but when i go into the debug folder its still the default icon and not the one i chose. [https://gyazo.com/5ae6a2a13a22327505ba8cc90ebdecf6 ]

Comment: I'll wager the icon is cached by Windows. Try *renaming* the .exe to something else or moving it to another folder and see if it's still the same.

Comment: i moved it and renamed it and the icon is still the same default one

Comment: ... Is the icon correct in the project properties window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Is it definitely the correct .exe? If you clean and rebuild the solution is the modified time right?

Comment: that actually worked, i cleaned and rebuilt the solution and it changed. thanks very much

Comment: No problem. Thanks for speedily accepting my answer too! :)