# Win forms icon of exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'd like to set icon of exe file, after publishing windows forms application on C# in Visual Studio.
What i do: Project->properties->icon->browse and setting the file.ico
rebuilding a project, publishing but nothing happends. published app still has deafult icon. What im doing wrong?

UPD: yes, i have read guide by microsoft and tried to add icon as resource. It takes no effect. (icon is valid and i also tried to use default generated icon from resource)

UPD2: I did everything correctly, but i tought that setup.exe file will have the icon. This where i was wrong. Programm will crieate icon, in folder with other programms.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-an-application-icon-visual-basic-csharp?view=vs-2022) can help you?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT nope, i tried to add icon as resource but still no effect

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32169608/17296043) is very similar to your question, did it work for you. You can try to clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Yes, very similar, but unfortunately cleaning and rebulding does not help.

Comment: Could you provide more information (such as screenshots) to help find a solution?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Yes, i think i can. What kind of screenshots you need? of my performed steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .exe can't find the directory of .ico file. To fix this you can add .ico file in `Resources -> Add Resource`. Select the icon in `Application -> Resources -> Icon and manifest -> select your icon`.

Comment: I added icon file to resources, selected icon (Resources\icon.ico), rebuilded app, and published. but still nothing

Comment: In general, it is not necessary to add the icon as ressource, it is sufficient to specify it with Project>Properties>Icon

Comment: Are you sure yours is a valid icon file? To check the validity, create a link to a file in Windows Explorer and then change it's icon by choosing your .ico file.

Comment: @HeinzKessler Yes, it's a valid file. I can set it as icon on any other file by hand. I also tried to set generated default icon (by VS), but still nothing.